# How to access same method with different objects in java

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, methods, constructor

I have created an two Arraylist and a Method for printing the elements of array list. How can I use the same method to print the elements of both ArrayList ?

Comment: Could you include the code you already have in your question? And maybe add an example. Your question is not really clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass the object of the created ArrayList to the function as paramter.

Here's a short example for printing the ArrayList:

Assuming you put the code inside a class, leaving a snippet here.
I'll demonstrate it with Integer examples.

```
static void printArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> a){
      for(Integer i:a)
           System.out.print(i+" ");
      System.out.println("");

}

//in the main function:
public static void main(String[] args){
      // input driver code
      ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<>();
      ArrayList<Integer> a2 = new ArrayList<>();
      a1.add(1);
      a2.add(10);
      printArrayList(a1);
      printArrayList(a2);
}
```

For more information on passing parameters - visit official documentation: [Function Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

For more information on ArrayList - visit official documentation:
[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: You are correct but I have created a custom ArrayList which inherits array list. Now how can I print the elements by using "dot operator" For ex : CustomArrayList al = new CustomArrayList().  al.printElement();

Comment: Can you include the code in your question, so it'll be more understandable?

Comment: You dont really have to inherit ArrayList, you create a class as per your needs and use that class as a type for the ArrayList instead of Integer as mentioned above.

Comment: I want to create a method to print the elements of ArrayList. How can I do that ?  There are two Arraylist which are 'a1' and 'a2' and the method is printElement(). How can I print the elements by using --- a1.printElement(); and a2.printElement(); These should print their respective elements

Answer (score 0):

you can do it:

```
public static void printBothListArgs(List<AnyType> listOne, List<AnyType> listTwo){
    Stream.concat(listOne.stream(), listTwo.stream()).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: This is probably not what the op was referring to.

Comment: RobOhRob I change the answer, you' re right

Comment: I don't understand your solution . It should be quite simple